# Proving f(n) is O(n^4)

Tags: time-complexity

I'm trying to figure out how I could prove  `f(n) = c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3` is of a certain complexity. I've simply expanded all the brackets and I figured it must be `O(n^4)`. Although I'm not sure how I could prove this.

I've tried to simplify it a bit and got the following:

`f(n) = c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3 <= c * n^4`

= `c_0 + c_1 * c_2 * c_3 * (n^4 + n^3) <= 2c * n^4`

But I'm not really sure what I could do from here. All the proofs I've done so far were simpler, with only one group of constants, and as such it was easy to choose some `c` and some `n` that would satisfy the inequality.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: n^4 + n^3 < 2n^4.  Then pick c=c0*c1*c2*c3*5 and you're done

Comment: Removing the multiplicative factor would still require me to find and prove that it holds for some n, and all the groups of constants. Not really sure how to get there. My lecturers used certain constants, e.g. for n = 3, c = 1

Comment: Thanks @GhostCat ; removed the tag

Comment: Unlike algorithms, functions don't have a notion of complexity. What you actually trying to prove is that `f(n) = O(n^4)` meaning `f(n) < cn^4, x → ∞` which you've proved in your answer

Answer (score 4):

`f(n) = c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3` is O(1), not O(n^4).

`O(x)` notation is about algorithmic complexity. Thus, either your question doesn't make sense (it's akin to: "What is the colour of happiness?" - two concepts that just do not apply to each other), or, it's asking about the algorithmic complexity in *calculating* that formula on a computer.

`O(n)` means something along the lines of: If you chart the 'size of the input' vs the 'time taken to finish the calculation for that input' / 'RAM required to perform the calculation for that input', you get a line that looks roughly like `y = C*x` - a line that runs at some angle (and not vertical or horizontal), in other words.

`O(n^2)` would mean that chart start to stabilize by looking like `y = C*x^2` as you increment n, and so on.

So, what's `n`? That depends on how the question is asked. For example, for an algorithm that "sorts a list", without further context, `n` is clearly 'the size of the list'.

The first problem here is that the operation you describe is a calculation, not a variable-sized input in the first place. Thus the only workable definition of what `n` might be is the actual value of `n` itself.

Thus, the question becomes: As you increment the value of `n` whilst running the method:

```
int calc(int n) {
    return c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3;
}
```

what happens to how long it takes to run the `calc` method, and what happens to how much memory it takes?

The answer is: Nothing happens; it's constant. `calc` takes about as long regardless of what `n` value you pass in. Therefore, that graph graphing 'value of n' vs 'time taken' is a horizontal line: `y = C` (where C is some constant). That's `O(1)`, not `O(n^4)`.

Possibly this has nothing whatsoever to do with big-O notation and you've confused a few things, in which case this is a question for a math-inclined Stack Overflow-esque site, not SO itself, which is for programmers.

Comment: Hey, I've used the tag "time-complexity" to specify which type of complexity I'm trying to figure out. Maybe I should add it to the question body. I'm also not sure how it's O(1), `f(n) = c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3` is a nested for loop (you can check my other question from today to see the code for it).

Comment: But `for` is nowhere in `f(n) = c_0 + n * c_1 * n * c_2 * (n(n+1))/2 * c_3`.

Comment: It's not a code, its counting the operations of an algorithm in polynomial form which is then used to prove the time complexity of said algorithm.

Comment: You need to explain that in your question.